# c# autotyping issue for dialogue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create an autotyping effect for my dialogue. Right now i am storing my dialogue in a nodebased editor. When i now want to let the text type out slowly it will make it appear 2 times, with only the second one being typed out.

```
public class DialogController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject dialogUI;

    [Header("Text")]
    [SerializeField] private Text textName;
    [SerializeField] private Text textBox;
    [SerializeField] public float typingSpeed;

    private void Awake()
    {
        ShowDialogUI(false);

        buttons.Add(button01);
        buttons.Add(button02);
        buttons.Add(button03);

        buttonsTexts.Add(buttonText01);
        buttonsTexts.Add(buttonText02);
        buttonsTexts.Add(buttonText03);
    }

    public void ShowDialogUI(bool show)
    {
        dialogUI.SetActive(show);
    }

    //loading in the text
    //TODO typing in the text when loading it in.
    public void SetText(string text)
    {
        textBox.StartCoroutine(Type());
        IEnumerator Type()
        {
            foreach (char letter in text.ToCharArray())
            {
                textBox.text = text += letter;
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(typingSpeed);
            }
        }
    }

    public void SetName(string text)
    {
        textName.text = text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you wrote this:

`textBox.text = text += letter;`

The full text will always be there completely, and one letter of the full text will be added one by one. Change it to

`textBox.text += letter;`

Comment: the problem is that when i do that, it writes all my dialogue nodes after another. Normally it writes only one like a sentence and then changing to the next. With that it doesnt do that anymore and just writes everything in one.